# min function in r lubridate gives integer near base date 1970-01-01 rather than the minimum?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

Here's an example. I need to extract the minimum observation date in order to expand the table back to the commencement date. It was working, now it is not: producing an integer or a date near the origin 1970-01-10? I've tried converting to numeric and back, using as.Date() and changing the na function to na.omit and read lots of posts. I'm sure it's simple but it has defeated me.

```
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

tt <- tibble(month = factor(rep("Mar", 15)),
             treatment = factor(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 5)),
             observation = c("", "", "", "05-04-2019", "",
                             "24-04-2019", "27-04-2019", "28-04-2019", "30-04-2019", "",
                             "05-05-2019", "09-05-2019", "12-05-2019", "20-05-2019", ""))

ts <- tt %>% mutate(observation = dmy(observation)) %>%
 group_by(treatment) %>%
  summarise(first = min(!is.na(observation)))
ts
# A tibble: 3 x 2

        treatment  first
        * <fct>      <int>
        1  a           0
        2  b           0
        3  c           0
```

Comment: I think you meant to do `summarise(first = min(observation, na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

ok the problem lay with the missing values. Remove them and it works :-)

```
summarise(first = min(na.omit(observation)))
```

to replace

```
summarise(first = min(!is.na(observation)))
```

madjac